# Mysql - How to retrieve all items that doesn't have a specific attribute?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table as below

```html
id      key       value    section
-----------------------------------
CT1   |    A   |   25   |   M-2
CT1   |    B   |   35   |   M-1
CT2   |    A   |   70   |   M-1
CT2   |    C   |   30   |   M-2
CT2   |    D   |   20   |   M-3
CT3   |    B   |   40   |   M-2
CT3   |    A   |   15   |   M-1
CT4   |    B   |   25   |   M-1
CT4   |    D   |   25   |   M-2
```

I need a way to return all ids which doesn't have certain key. For Example:

Ids that dont have **'D'**:
  CT1, CT3,

Is it possible to fetch this result from a MySQL query? I have searched for earlier questions as well. Couldn't find anything close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id      
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN key = 'D' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: `COUNT(key = 'D') = 0` sounds lighter

Comment: @NeverBackDown Ops, Sorry, I meant `SUM(keys = 'D') = 0` since yes, `COUNT(keys = 'D')` would fail because `COUNT`counts "non-NULL values" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE KEY NOT IN
    (SELECT KEY from YOURTABLE)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING count(key in ('D'))=0
```

you can change or add some elements to the list to exclude one or more ids.

Comment: This will return `CT1` since its key is `A`, which is not `D`

Answer (score 0):

The NOT IN method would have to look like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT id
 FROM mytable
 WHERE key = 'D')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WHERE NOT clause. Take a look at this example, this grabs everything where the value is not 25.

```
select * from table where not value=25
```